# vim syntax doesn't work at all

Tags: vim

I'm a beginner of vim, so I don't really know how vim work. And here I've got a problem. I can't use syntax in vim, it only works in some documents, such as
`vimrc` or the documents with `.vim`.

If I add `.vim` behind the document syntax run well, but another extension name 
then syntax doesn't work. I tried to fix it by modifying `/etc/vim/vimrc`:

```
add
syntax on
set background=dark
set hlsearch
set number
```

Every time I open a new file I can see the number on each line and the dark background, only syntax doesn't work .

Maybe this is too easy to you guys but I can't find any way to fix this. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

By the way I'm using Kali Linux (x64).

Comment: Usually, it is better to modify/add `~/.vimrc`. Modifying `/etc/vim/vimrc` seems to be a bad idea to me. Add this also and try `filetype indent on`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vim` tries to automatically determine the file type. If it detects a known type, it will use syntax highlighting. If it doesn't detect the type, it does not know which syntax to use (e.g. Java/vimrc/apache-config).

You can always check which file type `vim` thinks the current document has by using the command `:set filetype`. If the variable is empty, `vim` does now know which type of file this is and thus cannot use syntax highlighting.

There are several possibilities to "help" `vim` determine the file type.

1. The easiest is to use the correct file extension: If, for example, you open a file called `test.html`, `vim` knows that you will probably fill this file with HTML code and thus automatically sets the `filetype` variable to `html`.
2. You can also just write the file in a manner so that `vim` knows what kind of file this is. If, for example, a file begins with `#!/bin/bash`, `vim` knows that this is a `bash` script and sets the `filetype` variable to `bash`.
3. If all else fails, you can also tell `vim` the `filetype` explicitly. Either set it in the editor, e.g. `:set filetype=bash`, or use a [modeline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline), e.g. `# vim:filetype=bash`.

Regardless of whether the file type was correctly identified, `vim` needs to know which colours to use for which words. These are specified in "vim syntax files". On Debian, these are located in `/usr/share/vim/vim<your-vim-version>/syntax`, e.g. `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax`. I don't know if the location is the same on Kali, but I suspect it will be similar. If there is no vim syntax file for the file type you are editing, `vim` cannot help you. However, you might be able to find a syntax file online or in another package.

Comment: Glad to have helped. If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted", so others see that this solution works. Thanks!